# Unpermitted parameters utf8, method in update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, form-for

This one is driving me crazy...

**I have a form_for for which I want to update a `campaign` record.**

I'm getting the following error in logs when submitting the form and updating a campaign:

```
Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :_method, :authenticity_token, :campaign, :commit
```

**Campaign params**

```
def campaign_params
  params.permit(:box, :id, :name, :photo1, :delivery_date, :numberofitems, :extras, :card, :custom_message, :shipping_type, :totalitems, :companylogodesign, :companycarddesign,:selectedproducts => [])
end
```

**My routes:**

```
resources :campaigns
```

**My form:**

```
<%= form_with(model: campaign, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if campaign.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(campaign.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this campaign from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% campaign.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :status %>
    <%= form.number_field :status %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**In my controller action, I have the most simple update method:**

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @campaign.update(campaign_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @campaign, notice: 'Campaign was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @campaign }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @campaign.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Error Logs:**

```
Started PATCH "/campaigns/8" for ::1 at 2021-03-31 01:02:25 +0200
Processing by CampaignsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6/k7vBdzh/PxeGFnzVcny2w23Tm1XUd2BnIB1X0l56fDQA1Psudlb3uKzp983ER4RUdJMayeRD88wANRl1k6GA==", "campaign"=>{"name"=>"sdsd", "status"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Campaign", "id"=>"8"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.4/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Campaign Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns" WHERE "campaigns"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:93
Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :_method, :authenticity_token, :campaign, :commit
```

¿What am I missing? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Well...you're missing the definition of the `campaign_params` method in your question for starters. Without it we are just guessing.

Comment: Hello Max, just updated the params in the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are trying to achieve is something like:

```
if @campaign.update(campaign_params.require(:campaign).permit!)
```

But `permit!` is pretty risk. So I'd go with this:

```
if @campaign.update(campaign_params.require(:campaign).permit(:name, :status))
```

**Explanation**

See... When you declare a model/scope to your form, Rails will nest this parameters with the model/scope name.

So the parameters you are using inside the form are nested under the `campaign` key. By default, Rails will send some extra params, as you may have already noticed (`authenticity_token`,`commit`, `utf8`, etc...).

The unpermitted params error mean that you cannot use these params to update an entity (for security reasons) unless you explicitly declare it.

Comment: That did the trick! Using .require(:campaign) in the strong parameters.
Didn't know declaring a model in a form would do that nesting,
Thanks a lot!